# Changing ndkVersion to latest stable version didn't fix Gradle error

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I'm trying to build a Flutter project in Android Studio, but I'm encountering an error that says "Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 - Could not get unknown property 'ndkVersion' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension."
Here's the full error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 456

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not get unknown property 'ndkVersion' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried changing the ndkVersion to the latest stable version in the build.gradle file, but it didn't fix the issue.
Here's the updated build.gradle file where I changed the ndkVersion:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.food_delivery"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        ndkVersion "25.2.9519653"
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have added the capital v as capital letter and add a space ndkVersion "25.2.9519653" in the studio but forgot to mention here, but it does not fix the error

Comment: Isn't the `ndklVersion` property supposed to go directly into the `android {` block? (i.e. *not* inside `defaultConfig {`).